i want to mix a texture with noise texture and only want it to be shown where noise exists
i have a grunge texture mask

and noise texture, i want grunge to only be visible where it is white in noise.

i tried mixing both but, was losing the details of the grunge map while doing so. how do i maintain the values of grunge map and make it only be visible where noise is?

Multiply blend mode will accomplish this.
